# How to index two elements from a Python list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing, element

How come I can't index a Python list for multiple out-of-sequence index positions?

```
mylist = ['apple','guitar','shirt']
```

It's easy enough to get one element, but not more than one.

`mylist[0]` returns `'apple'`, but `mylist[0,2]` returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

So far, only this seems to work which looks hectic:

```
np.asarray(mylist)[[0,2]].tolist()
```

Comment: Access each element individually.  `mylist[0], mylist[2]`

Comment: The `TypeError` tellls us what is allowed when indexing a list.  That's basic Python!  Same for strings, tuples and dict.  Selection of several items with a list or tuple is a `numpy` addition.  Each indexable class has a `__getitem__` method.  The allowable indices are determined by that method, and thus can differ.

Comment: @JohnGordon individual elements is *not* the question. Multiple are

Comment: But @JohnGordon is right.  You have to access the list elements individually.  There's no way around that.  Even the `map` and `list comprehension` suggests do that.  That `array` round trip will be slow.

Comment: I see now what he was implying but it could've been said

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print([mylist[i] for i in [0, 2]])
# ['apple', 'shirt']
```

Or use [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(mylist)[[0, 2]])
# ['apple', 'shirt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Extended Slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
mylist = ['apple','guitar','shirt']
print(mylist[::2])
#Output: ['apple', 'shirt']
```

Comment: Works with sample data but probably not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Python list supports only integer and slice for indices. The standard slicing rule of python is as follow:

`i:j:k` inside the square bracket for accessing more than one element.
where `i` is the starting index, `j` is the ending index and `k` is the steps.

```
>>> list_ =  ['apple','guitar','shirt']
>>> mylist[0:2]
['apple', 'guitar']
```

if you want some random element as per some certain indices then use `List Comprehension` or just a `for` loop

There is an another way for accessing items from certain indices by using `map()` function.

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> indices_to_access = [0, 2]

>>> accessed_mapping = map(a_list.__getitem__, indices_to_access)
>>> accessed_list = list(accessed_mapping)

>>> accessed_list
[ 1, 3]
```

Comment: `i:j:k` is only good for fixed steps/increments. looking instead for something than can  flexibly admit manual indexing of list positions, e.g. `0, 2, 7, 6, 5, 21`

Comment: if not want to use `NumPy` then the `map()` function is the best way.

Comment: I update my answer above with an example of the map function, just map `__getitem__` with `index` list.

Answer (score 0):

A recommendation from me would be: use the NumPy library (import numpy as np). It will allow you to create a numpy array which has advantages over a standard list. Using the numpy array, you will be able to access as many items as you would like through a process called Fancy Indexing.

```
mylist[0] returns 'apple'
```

The above code/statement which was available in the question description depicts a Python programmer performing indexing- which is the process of passing the index position of a sinlge item in order to retrieve the item- However in the event of requiring multiple items, that would be difficult/not possible.

```
import numpy as np #import the numpy package

mylist = np.array(['apple','guitar','shirt']) #create the numpy array

mylist[[0,2]] #return the first and third items ONLY. (zero-indexed)
Out[11]: array(['apple', 'shirt'], dtype='<U6')
```

If you were to make use of the NumPy library in python (looking above), you would be able to create a NumPy array, which allows for more methods and operations to be performed on your array.

As compared to `mylist[0]` which returns a single/individual item only, Using `mylist[[0,2]]` we specify to the python compiler that we wish to retrieve exactly two elements from our list, and those elements are located at index positions '0' and '2'. (zero-indexed). Notice that we passed in the index positions of the desired elements in a list. Therefore instead of returning one element, we return two (or as many as you would like).